# Plotting data as colorful pixel

Tags: list-manipulation, plotting

I have a list of triple data. I want to plot them in this manner that

1. The first element to be considered a point in the x-axis.
2. The second element to be considered a point in the y-axis.
3. The third element to be considered as a color pixel in the XY-plane at (x,y) (the first element, the second element).

The spectrum of the colors used in the plot should be described in the description of the plot. How can I plot such a figure?

Here is my data:

```
data={{84, 60, 22.8591}, {84, 61, 8.74741}, {84, 62, 15.5119}, {85, 62, 18.525}, {86, 62, 23.3424}, {84, 63, 6.31806}, {85, 63, 6.67302}, {84, 64, 9.35025}, {85, 64, 5.90417}, {86, 64, 13.752}, {87, 64, 7.02938}, {88, 64, 21.5328}, {84, 65, 4.17085}, {85, 65, 4.09691}, {86, 65, 4.80203}, {87, 65, 4.79934}, {84, 66, 2.63347}, {85, 66, 3.02938}, {86, 66, 3.93298}, {87, 66, 4.36173}, {88, 66, 13.9777}, {84, 67, 1.54654}, {85, 67, 2.20898}, {86, 67, 2.08279}, {87, 67, 2.84856}, {91, 67, 2.83123}, {84, 68, 1.01284}, {85, 68, 1.56937}, {86, 68, 2.35025}, {87, 68, 2.50515}, {88, 68, 3.06819}, {84, 69, 0.170262}, {85, 69, 0.90309}, {86, 69, 1.33445}, {87, 69, 1.92324}, {83, 70, 0.623249}}
```

Comment: Looks like a perfect job for [ListDensityPlot](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListDensityPlot.html).

Comment: `scale = 1/Max[data[[All,3]] ]; Graphics[{ColorData["Rainbow"][scale #3], Point[{#1,#2}]}& @@@ data]` (untested)

Comment: `{{xmin, xmax}, {ymin, ymax}, {zmin, zmax}} = MinMax /@ Transpose[data];
vals = SparseArray[{#, #2} -> #3 & @@@ data][[xmin ;; xmax, ymin ;; ymax]];
MatrixPlot[vals, DataRange -> {{xmin, xmax}, {ymin, ymax}}]`

Comment: Thank you so much for your suggestions. But I need these colorful pixels in a coordinate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use @Szabolcs approach

```
    scale = 1/ Max[data[[All, 3]]];
 Graphics[{ColorData["ThermometerColors"][scale #3], Rectangle[{#1, #2}]} & @@@ data, Frame -> True]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you dear Okkes Dulgerci